# Filling textboxes in a webpage automatically

Tags: javascript

I've been asked to fill a form by my university which has 323 textboxes where each of them has to contain a number between 1 and 323. After manually adding a few numbers till 80 for example, I want a write a script that fills all the remaining textboxes with the numbers which have not been used.

How can this be accomplished? I mean, what should I use to accomplish this? If I make a JS script how do I run it on this page. Or is there some other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(x=0;x<323;x++) { document.getElementById("textBox"+x).value = x; }
```

As to how to run it on the page, you could

1. Download a copy of the page
2. Insert this script
3. Update the form to submit remotely (add http://www etc.)
4. Load the page (which inserts all the values)
5. Submit the form

Comment: Thanks Steve. Can you please elaborate on point 3 you've mentioned.

Comment: The `<form>` tag's `action` attribute likely points to a local URL, something like `submit.php`. You'll need to modify the attribute to lead to `http://example.edu/path/to/form/submit.php` so the data gets there properly.

Comment: Just paste this into address bar:
"javascript:for(x=0;x<323;x++){document.getElementById("textBox"+x).value=x;}" (w/o quotes).
And press [Enter] there. That's all.

Comment: Sorry Prakhar, my comment notifier must have missed your comment. Coming back to it, it's as @ceejayoz said.  Find the form in the HTML you downloaded: it will have a `action` attribute that's probably relative to the website. You'll probably have to update it to http address you want the form to point to.